# Postgresql database migration to other host

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, artifactory

Im trying to move my postgres db from one host (xenial) to another (focal). I've tried using pgdump for it

```
pg_dump -d mydb > backup.sql
```

But the problem is that after I've restored db on my new host with

```
psql -d mydb < backup.sql
```

I get an error in logs: "Your collation seems to have change: rebuild your index then empty the table access_db_check". I have no problem doing that but I want to figure out what causing collation to change.
DB on new and old host both have |UTF8|en_US.UTF-8|en_US.UTF-8 for encoding|Collate|Ctype. Maybe it's because of version difference? Old on is 12.7-1 and new one is 12.9

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm if the source and destination postgres versions are same.

If yes, can you check if the collation of your source database and destination database is same. Mostly it should be "UTF-8"

The below command might help you.
`SELECT datcollate FROM pg_database WHERE datname='<database name>';`

Comment: Like I said in my original post original db is being used by postgres 12.7-1 and new one by 12.9

Yeah, I've checked again and they are both en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. If possible, try to import back on another new database on the source instance itself to get a better clarity. If we are able to import, only clause will be the different postgres versions (I do agree that collation is same but versions are different)